# POST a test file using chef http_request method on another server

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I want to post a text file on server using chef http_request method.
Here i write something but its not working-

```
http_request "post a file" do
  action :post
  url "http://<server_ip>/php/upload.php"
  headers "Content-Type" => "text/plain"
  message ::File.read("#{filename}")
end
```

Can anyone please suggest how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

File uploads, which it sounds like you're trying to do, require more complex HTTP machinery than `http_request` implements. You'll have to do it yourself using a `ruby_block` and something like Faraday or `Chef::HTTP`.